# Neither the Global Exception Filter or the Application_Error are Catching Unhandled Exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, automapper

I have a global exception filter named `LogErrorAttribute`:

```
public class LogErrorAttribute : IExceptionFilter
{
    private ILogUtils logUtils;

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.logUtils == null)
        {
            this.logUtils = StructureMapConfig.Container.GetInstance<ILogUtils>();
        }

        this.logUtils.LogError(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Unknown error.", filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

It's registered along with the standard `HandleErrorAttribute` filter:

```
filters.Add(new LogErrorAttribute());
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

I'm registering those filters like this:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

I also have an `Application_Error` fallback:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    //Logging goes here

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
        }
        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
    }

    // Avoid IIS7 getting involved
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    // Execute the error controller
    if (exception != null)
    {
        this.errorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "An unknown exception has occurred.", exception);
    }
    else if (httpException != null)
    {
        this.errorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "An unknown HTTP exception has occurred.", httpException);
    }
    else
    {
        this.errorLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "An unknown error has occurred.");
    }
}
```

Now, I have an API controller that grabs some data from the database and then uses `AutoMapper` to map the models to view models:

```
var viewModels = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(users, new List<UserViewModel>());
```

Inside that `AutoMapper` configuration a custom resolver executes for one of the properties:

```
var appModuleAssignments = this.appModuleAssignmentManager.Get(userId);
var appModules = appModuleAssignments.Select(x => this.appModuleManager.Get(x.AppModuleId));
return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(appModules, new List<AppModuleViewModel>());
```

At the moment I'm forcing the `appModuleManager.Get` statement to throw a regular exception:

```
throw new Exception("Testing global filter.");
```

This subsequently throws an exception in `AutoMapper`, both of which are unhandled, however neither the global filter or the `Application_Error` are picking up this exception.

What did I do wrong here?

---

A couple things I have done since posting:

1. Added the `customErrors` attribute to the `Web.config` to turn them `on`.
2. Removed the `HandleErrorAttribute` global filter because I realized it was setting the error to handled if it were even running. I would not expect it to be executing anyway because this error occurs outside the controller, but it would have likely bit me later.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" but have you tried cleaning (deleting) the bin and obj folders and then clearing web browser cache? Seems like your doing everything correctly (from an initial glance)

Comment: @Pseudonym I totally understand, but yep, I've been down that road. 

Comment: Okay I will have to peruse your question some more

Comment: The sole Application_Error works in all our mvc apps, no filters required. I don't remember anything extra here.

Comment: @WiktorZychla exactly how I suspected it **should** work. LOL. Does it by chance have something to do with `AutoMapper` you think? I wouldn't think so because even the `AutoMapper` exception is *unhandled.*

Comment: Are you on IIS with .NET 4 integrated mode pool?

Comment: @WiktorZychla currently I'm operating on IIS Express via VS 2015.

Comment: Could you try the very same code on "near-production environment" which would be iis then? It could just work differently with iis express/vs/debugger attached. If my theory is true and this just works when you move to IIS, you could somehow neglect the fact it works differently in a dev environment.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I sure will give that a shot. It'll be sometime tonight probably. Thanks!

Comment: `Added the customErrors attribute to the Web.config to turn them on.` But as I know it should be `off` for the `Application_Error` to hit. Try it

Comment: check the web.config to make sure compilation element has set it to debug="true" ? in <system.web> <compilation> tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is that you are adding a **MVC** Exception Filter rather than a **Web API** Exception Filter.

Your implementation checks for `ExceptionContext` rather than `HttpActionExecutedContext`

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
```

Since the framework will raises a **Http Exception** rather than a **MVC Exception**, your `OnException` override method is not triggered.

So, a more complete example:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute

    {
       public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)

      {

        message = "Web API Error";
        status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        actionExecutedContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(message, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"),
            StatusCode = status
        };

        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Another important step is to register your Global Web API Exception Filter in WebApiConfig.cs, in the `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` method.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

...

config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter());

}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this change a shot. But, even if this fixes the filter, why doesn't the global handler pick up the error?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, I added to my answer. The jist is that **HTTP Context** is different than **MVC context**. The explanation of why is rather involved. The easiest way to explain it is that a **Web API** is a much lighter framework than the full **MVC** Framework

Comment: @DaveAlperovich - I am not sure how you came to this conclusion. The OP didn't give any indication he is using Web API, neither in the question itself or the tags. So, being that he is apparently going to try it, it appears your assumption is correct. Yet another case where someone incorrectly tagged their question, as this appears to have nothing at all to do with ASP.NET MVC, which is a completely different framework than  Web API. I am sure the answer would have came quicker had that information been included in the question.

Comment: @NightOwl888, interesting point. There is only one hint. In the middle of OP's post, you will find **"Now, I have an API controller that grabs some data from the database"**. Granted, "an API controller" doesn't have to mean **Web API**, but going by convention and the nature of OP's problem, I concluded must be using **Web API**, not **MVC** framework. Perhaps we should re-tag the question, but I'm waiting for final confirmation...

Comment: @DaveAlperovich you are correct that it's a Web API controller. I'm going to be trying this solution today. I'll get back to you.

Comment: That is correct you have to use ExceptionFilterAttribute or IFilter to implement filter for web api. you cannot catch global errors as you do in mvc pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Alperovich answer will solve your issue by using **HttpActionExecutedContext**

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
```

However as you are trying to capture all possible exceptions your application might generate then apart from exception filters one should use message handlers as well. A detailed explanation can be find here - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling.

In summary, there are a number of cases that exception filters can’t handle. For example:

- Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
- Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
- Exceptions thrown during routing.
- Exceptions thrown during response content serialization

So, **If an unhandled error occurs from anywhere within the application, your Exception Handler will catch it and allow you to take specific action**.

```
//Global exception handler that will be used to catch any error
public class MyExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        private class ErrorInformation
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }            
        }

        public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
        {
            context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
              new ErrorInformation { Message="An unexpected error occured. Please try again later.", ErrorDate=DateTime.UtcNow }));
        }
   }
```